# Manage sequences using HQL

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, hql, sequence-sql

**TLDR: There is a way to manage sequences in relational database using pure Hibernate or Spring?**

I am writing a library in java That need to create and get the next value of a sequence. I can't use native sql because the database can be Oracle , H2 or Postgresql. In my opinion hql will be the best answer because it's not depend on the database type.

Thanks For any kind of help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty confident nothing like this exists in JPA nor in Spring (or Spring Data). There might be something useful internally in Hibernate and other JPA implementations but it is most certainly not intended for direct use.

If you want something ready-made [jOOQ has support for this](https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.0/manual/sql-execution/sequence-execution/).

Comment: Sounds like a good library  that I was not aware of, I'll try it!

Answer (score 0):

```
There are many different id generation options in hibernate. You can choose one of these strategies:
The Auto Strategy
The Identity Strategy
The Sequence Strategy
The Table Strategy
```

http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/entity/generated

Comment: I dont have any entity , I just want to get the next value of sequence